# Qunit: Test leakage

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I have a leakage problem when testing my jQuery plugin. The problem occurs when I want to mock out a value or function on a literal object.

Example:

```
test('Overwrite some default setting', function(){
    $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar = 'foo';
});

test('Bar should be undefined', function(){
    equals( $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar, undefined );
});
```

This test will fail because the first test added the 'bar' var to defaults. I fixed it with the following code but taking a copy of a copy doesn't look very elegant.

```
$(function(){

    /*
     * Trolley Button Base: Options.
     */

    var defaults_copy = $.extend({}, $.fn.plugin.defaults );

    var setdown = {
        setup : function(){
            $.fn.plugin.defaults = $.extend({}, defaults_copy);
        },

        teardown : function(){ }
    };

    module('Test leakage', setdown );

    test('Overwrite some default setting', function(){
        $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar = 'foo';
    });

    test('Bar should be undefined', function(){
        equals( $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar, undefined );
    });

})
```

Also if I have a few objects in the jQuery namespace it might become a little messy if I have to take multiple copies of each object. So was wondering does anybody have a better solution to 'reset' all objects?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design for QUnit. At the end of each test, you should clean up any state changes you've made. I don't know of a way to automatically do that -- you have to write the code to undo the effects of any test code you've written, like this:

```
test('Overwrite some default setting', function(){
    // test code
    $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar = 'foo';

    // cleanup code
    delete $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar;
});

test('Bar should be undefined', function(){
    equals( $.fn.plugin.defaults.bar, undefined );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent issues with test order dependency and to isolate your unit tests fully, you will need to manually implement Test level setup and tear down functionality by creating a function for each and including it at the beginning and end of each of your test methods:

e.g.
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    // Test Setup/TearDown
    function codeUnderTestModuleTestSetup() {
        //any setup needed
    }

    function resetDefaults() {
        //code in here to reset defaults
    }

    function resetSomethingElse() {
        //code in here to reset something else
    }

    function codeUnderTestModuleTestTearDown() {
        resetDefaults();
        resetSomethingElse();
    }

    //Tests
    module('Your module title Test Harness');    

    test('FunctionUnderTest_Behaviour_ExpectedResult', 1, function () {
        codeUnderTestModuleTestSetup();

        //Arrange
        //code removed

        //Act
        //Code removed

        //Assert
        //Code removed

        codeUnderTestModuleTestTearDown();
    });

}
```

You can manually implement module level and test run level setup and teardown functions too, if necessary.